# Gauss' Law Application

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I was reading about the electric field at a radial distance $r$ from an infinitely long, thin wire having a linear charge density $\lambda$. Although I understood how it's derived using Gauss' Law, I am getting a different result when the Gaussian Surface is chosen differently. I've attached images which show the Gaussian Surfaces chosen in both cases, and how I proceeded to derive it.
(Note: I've just shown a part of the infinitely long wire in the below images).
Can someone tell why is the 2nd derivation giving me that result?

The first image shows the correct derivation, and the second image is the derivation that I tried, but got an answer different from what I expected.
[image: This is the first derivation (which gives the correct result).]

[image: This is the second derivation (which I had tried). Infact, from this derivation, the electric field comes out to be a function of r₀, and not r]

PS: Sorry for the slightly illegible writing, wrote with a mouse :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think again which direction the ${\bf E}$-lines from the long wire are pointing.  In the plane of the paper, yes they are pointing purely left and right.  However what about the lines coming out of the page?  Which direction are they pointing and are they perpendicular to your Gaussian surface?

The reason the first one works is because at all points on the cylinder the ${\bf E}$-field lines are either perfectly perpendicular to the curved surface, or perfectly parallel to the flat edge.  In maths speak, here ${\bf E}\cdot\text{d}{\bf S}=|{\bf E}||\text{d}{\bf S}|\text{ or }0$ only.

The second one doesn't work, because now most of the field lines (except for the select few you've drawn) are at funny angles to your surface, and you would have to do some component weighting to get the right answer.  Maths again, here ${\bf E}\cdot\text{d}{\bf S}\neq|{\bf E}||\text{d}{\bf S}|$ in general.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense! I overlooked the fact that there will be field lines coming out of the plane of the paper. Thank you!